# How can I ensure search engines don't index my site during development?

Tags: html

I am in the process of developing a website. I am using much example placeholder text as well as dummy images. I want to ensure that Google does not index my pages while I am still in development.

Is there any code I can add to my pages to ensure search engines do not index my site at this time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to develop online... ;) There are two easy ways to do this.

Create a robots.txt file (http://www.robotstxt.org/

Use htaccess for password access only (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess)

Answer (score 5):

Ideally, you shouldn't be developing a site on the public front in the first place!

But you can edit your `robots.txt` like so:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Answer (score 1):

set the robots.txt

http://www.robotstxt.org/

this should impact all the search engines you care about.

(or you could temporarily password protect the site.)

Answer (score 1):

Try using [robots.txt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard). But beware that it [*is not a security measure*](http://diovo.com/2008/09/robotstxt-is-not-a-security-measure/). Some bots will completely [ignore it](http://www.kloth.net/internet/badbots.php).

Some [history](http://www.antipope.org/charlie/blog-static/2009/06/how_i_got_here_in_the_end_part_3.html) on robots.txt.

As others have said, you really shouldn't be developing your site in public. A better solution is to develop on a local machine that isn't internet-facing, or restrict access to the portions of your site that are under development.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file called "robots.txt" at the root directory of your website and inside it put:

```
Disallow: /
```

And upload it. Google will follow your robots.txt file, but not all crawlers will pay attention to it.

Answer (score 0):

adding a robots.txt file should stop sites from indexing it.

You can find more information here http://www.robotstxt.org/ but basically it tells the web robots/spiders to ignore the site.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can find some suggest to your problem in a similar question that you can find here:

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20964/best-way-to-take-down-site-for-a-long-period-while-i-develop-it/20965

Basically you can use robots.txt, create a private folder or Return 403 (use HTTP authentication) for all URLs on your development site.

Answer (score -1):

Add meta-tag `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">` see [Google support](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=en)

Comment: That's a relative poor solution compared to the others. It only works for HTML documents and it has to be removed from every HTML document when the site is ready to go public.

Comment: In my case I had a just a single HTML file in S3 static hosting and all I needed. I would like to see all the options, not just the most complicated and powerful ones.